# Electron stuff mock on the React side

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, electron, desktop-application

I work on electron + react application and faced problem with testing. I need some electron stuff on react side which I import like below.

```
const electron = window.require ? window.require('electron') : {};
const { ipcRenderer, desktopCapturer } = electron;
```

How to mock electron object that I get from window require ? I tried:

```
global.window.require = jest.fn(() => ({
    electron: {
        ipcRenderer: {
            send: jest.fn(),
        },
        desktopCapturer: {
            getSources: [{ id: 'test'}]
        },
    }
}));
```

but it didn't work.